# Format data to split records after comma using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format:

```
 id : 1234, name :  ABC, XYZ
 id : 7891, name :  MNO
```

I am trying to achieve the data in below format:

```
 id : 1234, name :  ABC
 id : 1234, name :  XYZ
 id : 7891, name :  MNO
```

I am able to get the first line done, but how to carry the id to the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ $NF=$NF }
     $NF ~ /,/{ 
         gsub(/[[:space:]]*/, "", $NF);
         len=split($NF, a, ",");
         for (i=1; i<=len; i++) { $NF=a[i]; print $0 }
         next 
     }1' FS=' +: +' OFS=' : ' file
```

The output:

```
id : 1234, name : ABC
id : 1234, name : XYZ
id : 7891, name : MNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution

```
awk -F: '
{
a=split($NF,b,",");
for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
  {
  sub(/^ */,"",b[i]);
  $NF=" "b[i];
  print $0
  }
}
' OFS=: infile
```

Or With sed

```
sed -n '
s/.*/&,/
:A
h
s/\(.*:.*:\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1\3/
x
s/\(.*:.*:\)\([[:blank:]]*\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1 \3/p
x
/,$/bA
' infile
```